# Storybook does not support v-calendar of vuetify

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, storybook, vcalendar

I tried adding v-calendar component from vuetify in Storybook as follows but it fails to load with error given in image below. Is it not supported?
Same goes with v-date-picker.

**Packages:**
"@storybook/vue": ">=5.3.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vuetify": "^2.2.11",

```
//calendar.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <v-calendar color="primary"
      ref="calendar"
        v-model="focus"
        type="category"
        category-show-all
        :categories="categories"
        :events="events">
    </v-calendar>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
Vue.use(Vuetify);

@Component
export default class Calendar extends Vue {
  @Prop({default:()=>{ return []}}) detectionsData!: [];

  focus= '';
  events= [];
  categories= ['John Smith', 'Tori Walker'];  
}
</script>
```

[image]

```
// calendar.stories.ts
import myCalendar from "../components/Calendar.vue";
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

export default {
    title: 'Calendar-View',
    component: myCalendar,
};
const Template = (args: any, { argTypes }: any) => ({
    props: Object.keys(argTypes),
    components: { myCalendar },
    template: '<my-calendar/>',
});

Template.args = {}

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = ({})
```

Comment: when I check $veitify on console in normal 'npm run serve', it shows 'lang' property correctly. But when I run it in storybook with 'npm run storybook', the 'lang' property of '$vuetify' variable is missing. I think this issue might be because of import implementations in webpack. Any clues anyone???

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved after providing following attribute to calendar component

```
locale="en"
```